# segmentation fault with bison and flex

Tags: bison, lex

I was trying learn lex and yacc using the oreilly book. I tried following example from book, but it gives segmentation fault.

```
%{
 /**
  * A lexer for the basic grammar to use for recognizing English sentences.
  */

  #include <stdio.h>
  extern FILE *yyin;
%}

%token NOUN PRONOUN VERB ADVERB ADJECTIVE PREPOSITION CONJUNCTION

%%
sentence: subject VERB object{ printf("Sentence is valid.\n");}
 ;

subject: NOUN
 | PRONOUN
 ;
object:  NOUN
 ;
%%


main()
{
 while(!feof(yyin)) {
  yyparse();
 }

}
yyerror(char *s)
{
 fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}
```

i'm using flex and bison. 
I'm getting segmentation fault in main function, in the while loop. It is not entering at all to the loop.

Any thoughts?
Thanks,
Robert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is yyin actually given a meaningful value somewhere?  Perhaps try assigning it:

```
yyin = stdin;
```

Just before the main loop.

EDIT: and maybe try not defining it "extern" unless it's actually defined somewhere else.