# y.tab.c not generated on fedora with bison -d

Tags: c, fedora, bison, fedora20

**Update:** So turns out all I had to do to make bison generate `t.tab.c` was to use the `-y` switch. However, my original assumption of a problem with the code when the problem gave me a **segfault** seems correct according to the answers posted. Here is what it all looks like now:

[image: Segfaulting code]

The source is exactly the same as downloaded from the O'reilly website and I triple checked the ch1-04 code that this is based on. It's all extremely *simple* stuff. A program that recognises a sentence as a `subject VERB and object` Here is the code : [ch1-05.l](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzeuhqtser37ksw/ch1-05.l?dl=0), [ch1-05.y](https://www.dropbox.com/s/no51waf0kuwkzcr/ch1-05.y?dl=0), [ch1-05y.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5jwb2dy2evs6g7/ch1-05y.h?dl=0)

Original Question:

---

So succinctly I'm working my way to learning how to build a compiler.

I'm not very used to C\C++ and have never used lex and yacc before, this I'm following [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920002.do):
[image: Lex & Yacc Cover]

---

Now, in the book on page 21 this is what it says:

[image: Lex & Yacc Page 21]

Now being on fedora 2 I don't have yacc. I installed **bison**.

Here is what the scene on my fedora looks like:

[image: Terminal (Shot5)]

Do notice I am using **-d**.

If you'd really like to see the code here is : [ch1-05.l](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qzeuhqtser37ksw/ch1-05.l?dl=0), [ch1-05.y](https://www.dropbox.com/s/no51waf0kuwkzcr/ch1-05.y?dl=0), [ch1-05y.h](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z5jwb2dy2evs6g7/ch1-05y.h?dl=0)

---

I was actually *silly enough* and thought `y.tab.c` was an mistake in the book and they actually meant `ch1-05.tab.c`. I tried compiling with that and it gave me a segmentation fault :/ It took me a day to realize there is supposed to be a `y.tab.c` there.

I'm quite constantly checking SO so anything you need from me I will respond quick. I'd really like to get this done with because I'm on holiday due to a brain haemorrhage and I'd like to get this book complete soon. I have quite a list of books and quite a holiday :D

Comment: Hve you tried 'man bison'

Comment: @stark yes, when I did it gives me an **empty** page in the bash terminal that says on the top **Manual page bison(1) line ?/? (END) (press h for help or q to quit**. **But** I remember seeing `-d` somewhere as for bison so I tried it.

Comment: You can also type 'man bison' into google although I am not responsible for your safe search settings.

Comment: The segfault problem probably comes from the fact that recent versions of `flex` initialize `yyin` and `yyout` to `NULL` instead of `stdin` and `stdout`. You can get the traditional behaviour by giving `flex` the `--stdinit` command-line flag. There might be other incompatibilities between modern `flex` and the version of `lex` used in that book.

Comment: @rici yep. Exactly what you said and thats in the marked answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking that bison would produce `ch1-05.tab.c` instead of `y.tab.c` wasn't silly at all, in fact that's what it did.  Bison is GNU's version of Yacc, and though it is compatible with it in terms of grammar description, there are some differences in usage.

If you want to revert to conservative Yacc mode, try `bison -y [...]`:

```
   -y
   --yacc
   --fixed-output-files
          Equivalent  to  -o  y.tab.c;  the  parser  output file is called
          y.tab.c, and the other outputs are called y.output and  y.tab.h.
          The purpose of this switch is to imitate yacc’s output file name
          conventions.  Thus, the following shell  script  can  substitute
          for yacc and is often installed as yacc:

          bison -y "$@"
```

If you get a segfault running you program, it's more likely due to a programming error on your side.  How did you link you binary ?

( ... some googling later ... )

Try this in `ch1-05.y`:

```
extern FILE *yyin;

main()
{  
   yyin = stdin;  /* initialize yyin */
   while(!feof(yyin)) {
      yyparse();
   }
}
```

Comment: I linked my binary according to the book : `gcc -o example-05.n    lex.yy.o ch1-05.tab.o -ll`

Comment: Here is what is looks like with the segfault : https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t8nbr6gvzq5m5d/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-26%2020%3A18%3A15.png?dl=0

Comment: Apparently it fails because `yyin` wasn't initialized.  I just found a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3317572/segmentation-fault-with-bison-and-flex).

Comment: @gideon: just add `yyin = stdin;` first thing in `main()` and it should be fine.

Comment: thank you VERY much. It worked :) The program somehow doesn't seem to recognize valid sentences still, saying "syntax error" but that I shall debug and figure out.

Answer (score 1):

The default output file name is one of the differences between yacc and bison. If you use `bison -y` then it will act more like yacc and produce a `y.tab.c` (and `y.tab.h` if `-d` is also used).

The `-y` option will just change the name of `ch1-05.tab.c` to `y.tab.c`, it won't solve the bug that caused your segfault.

Comment: really? So Using `ch1-05.tab.c` instead of `y.tab.c` was _correct_ ?

Comment: [Screenie, worked, with segfault](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9t8nbr6gvzq5m5d/Screenshot%20from%202014-11-26%2020%3A18%3A15.png?dl=0). However, I double and triple checked the `ch1-04` code that this is based on and it's exactly like the book and is pretty correct to me atleast.

Comment: Yes so now you have a segfault and you need to debug it. There are tools that might help, like gdb. I feel like there should be a canonical "How To Trace A Segfault" question on stackoverflow but I don't see it anywhere. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876357/determine-the-line-of-c-code-that-causes-a-segmentation-fault) is a good start I guess.